# Spring cannot resolve configuration property

Tags: spring

I am trying to add an additional map of properties in my .yaml file.

unfortunately it is failing even in the first value:
[image]

it is highlined

Here is my Mappings.class (with enabled configuartion properties annotation pointing to this class)
[image]

and this is my another one with the filters
[image]

I have added the dependency of configuration processor for spring-boot....

The most crazy thing is that when I get the configurableEnvironmentContext from the SpringContainer it says thay these properties are read correctly:

[image]

Any ideas why it could fails????

Comment: it is possible that you need `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mappings.filters")` but please add the code and not screenshots , this is a basic guideline in SO forum.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos this doesn't helps, I already tried. And in the another module is done exactly the same and it is working.
I don't wont to expose business code - not a good practice.
I mainly described the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was that In the Mappings class the attribute was a collection (List) and by default I named it as filters with ("S").

Make sure your prefix/yaml/parrent class attribute names are identical.
Probably Spring is removing all the symbols, uppercases and etc and then matching...